# Can I use HD directly in SATA with Dell T440 Server?

Tags: dell

Can i connect hd with operating system directly to SATA motherboard?

It has a hot plug front panel, but I intend to plug the hard drive directly into the motherboard's SATA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i connect hd with operating system directly to SATA motherboard?

Yes

Comment: Can I connect outside of the disk controller?

So even if the server has 8 hot-plug front inputs, could you connect two other hard drives directly to the motherboard?

Comment: Yes, there are SATA ports on the systemboard, two of one physical connector type and one using a different one. Look in the manual - they're labelled 'SATA A' and 'SATA B'.